# Getting repetitive "Cannot find type definition" error on VS Code, but not in TSC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I have an app based on NextJS using Typescript (which is based on React).

I found myself installing `npm i -D @types/XXX` enough times to figure out that something isn't right. After looking at my `tsconfig.json` file, I noticed that `compilerOptions.typeRoots` was missing, so I added the following lines:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
}
```

After restarting my IDE, I could finally get the type declarations of my packages without manually installing the types. But, there's an issue when VS Code screams I have 448 problems (which is the same problem all over):

[image: what the f*** vsc?]

to make sure it's not actually TSC problem, I ran `next dev` which basically runs `tsc` (among other things) and it runs without any issue. I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 2):

In general, types are seperate npm packages, so you need to manually install them. beside of this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules"
        }
    }
]
}
```

has syntax error

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
}
```

this is my typeRoots configuration

```
"typeRoots": ["./@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
```

first one is for local types and the latter is for installed node module types.

**EDIT:**

If you have some packages which doesn't have types, you have three option:

1. create type declarations by implementing them properly

`declare module "@ampproject" {
        export function some_function(str: string): string;
    };`

2. create global.d.ts inside types directory and add `declare module "*"` or just for @ampproject `declare module "@ampproject";`
3. cast object to any

Comment: You're right about the syntax error, although I wrote it wrong just here. I didn't remove `@ampproject` from my dependencies. In fact, the error was thrown even before I removed some of the types. There are several packages that I use that don't have @types such as `react-hook-form`. So I'm not sure why this error is thrown

Comment: option 1 and 2 doesn't sound like a good idea. Each package should have their own declarations. option 3 isn't relevant because it's coming from `tsconfig.js` line 1. I'm not even using it. If your answer covers all of the scenarios, then I should've post an issue on GitHub instead of asking on Stackoverlflow. thanks for helping tho.